# How can I clear my textboxes in my Windows Presentation Foundation?

Tags: c#, wpf, barcode

I have an Application build in WPF. It have a Textbox that will always accept only 10 digits and is always ready for Scanning ID `Barcode`  Contains 10 Digits or Entering Number with Keyboard.

Now some Customers are entering just 2 digits and leaving system as it is. Let us say he write `12` in TextBox and left it. When new Customer is coming he is Scanning his Id without noticing that there is something already written in the TextBox. So New Number is coming like this `1224444444` and two numbers are missing that is `34`.

How can I clear Textbox before Scanning or Before Writing?

Comment: First edit your question, according to appropriate wording

Comment: @NATS thanks, It's done :)

Answer (score 1):

some example code of exactly how you are attempting this would be useful.

A WPF textbox can be cleared by either calling the .Clear method, or simply by setting the "Text" property of the Textbox to string.empty.

With regards to most barcode scanners i've seen and used (usually KB emulation), you can usually set them up to get a prefix and suffix on the data so that you can detect scan input over keyboard input. You can then detect a scan and clear the textbox prior to entering the new information

Comment: I am using normal Motorola Scanner for Scanning.  As every cashier in supermarkets is using. No code is written to control it. Scanning barcodes and getting output only. nothing else

Answer (score 0):

react at the new scanevent from the barcodescanner and clear the textbox.text with string.empty

Comment: How to get new scanevent from barcodescanner ???

Comment: there is a way to implement the software of the scanner in your solution like a .dll

Comment: i dont know your solution or scannersoftware, but in this dll it will be an event